# UWP C# BackgoundUploader not working

Tags: c#, php, uwp, background-transfer

SO I'm trying to upload a file to my webserver using C#, UWP, and the background uploader namespace. Here is my C# code:

```
private async Task JamCloud_Upload_MP3()
    {
        try
        {

        Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.example.com/upload/upload.php");
        var file = storagefile.file;

        BackgroundUploader uploader = new BackgroundUploader();
        uploader.SetRequestHeader("userfile", file.Name);

        UploadOperation upload = uploader.CreateUpload(uri, file);

            // Attach progress and completion handlers.
            await upload.StartAsync();
        //HandleUploadAsync(upload, true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            f.MessageBox("Upload Error: "+ ex);
        }
    }
```

So, by default the upload.method is POST. So Im not sure how to catch this POST on the server so I wrote a PHP file like I was catching a post from a html form post.

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

$uploaddir = '/home/example/public_html/upload/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile);
}

?>
```

It doesnt seem to be working.... can anyone help me?

Comment: Here you we get the response that return by the server in UploadOperation..it is possible to get JSON response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out.

1. Changed the upload.method = "PUT"; //in the C# code default was POST
2. Change the PHP script to:

   ```
   <?php
   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT'){
       /* PUT data comes in on the stdin stream */
       $putdata = fopen("php://input", "r");

       /* Open a file for writing */
       $fp = fopen($_SERVER['HTTP_USERFILE'], "w");

       /* Read the data 1 KB at a time
          and write to the file */
       while ($data = fread($putdata, 1024))
         fwrite($fp, $data);

       /* Close the streams */
       fclose($fp);
       fclose($putdata);
   }   
   ?>
   ```

Comment: Was struggling a long time with this before I saw this post. Works great! Thanks!